A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_core' in Flutter
I am facing an issue in a Flutter project while using Firebase.
I have tested various methods, including changing the package version, changing the Gradle version, clearing cache, etc., but none of them worked, I even tried to add jar libs manually.
The project runs normally, but when I add the firebase_core package, I encounter the following error:
A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_core'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':firebase_core:classpath'.
   > Could not find manifest-merger-31.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:31.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/31.1.2/manifest-merger-31.1.2.jar
   > Could not find aaptcompiler-8.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:8.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aaptcompiler/8.1.2/aaptcompiler-8.1.2.jar
   > Could not find crash-31.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:31.1.2).

.
.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_core' of type org.gradle.api.Project.


settings.gradle:
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "com.android.application" version "8.4.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.2" apply false
}

build.gradle:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() // Add Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral() // Add Maven Central repository
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // Add Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral() // Add Maven Central repository
    }

}


rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


build.gradle(app):
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"


}

android {
    namespace = "com.app.placetory"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.app.placetory"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.
        minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '34.0.0'
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

dependencies {
    implementation files('libs\\google-services-4.3.15.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\manifest-merger-31.1.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\annotations-31.1.2.jar')

}


